# Shall i use Apigee.com API proxy for my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, web

I have generated a customized API proxy using Apigee.com and using that Customized API proxy problem with Cross origin Request Issue was resolved but can anyone tell me is this a reliable solution?

Comment: can I know the purpose of your api and used for which type of project?

Comment: @ Bhavik Patel: we have a requirement to validate the VAT id for Europe region.We have generated a API for that third party VAT web service using Apigee.com –